# Android: GetLastKnownLocation always returns old location

Tags: android, locationmanager

**The problem is:**

2 hours back I was in a complete different location(home). Now currently I am in some other location(office)where my application shows my current location as home. Same thing happened at home yesterday, when it was showing office as my current location.

**Code:**

```
      if (isNetworkEnabled) {
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0, this);
      if (locationManager != null) {
      location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
      if (location != null) {
      latitude = location.getLatitude();
      longitude = location.getLongitude();
       }
     } 
   }
```

Why my app isn't able to get a new/fresh location from the provider.

Thank You

Comment: What does google maps show as your last known location when you run this code? It may have updated your gps location but not your network location. This code doesn't actually  update your location using network or GPS, it just asks for previously stored locations.

Comment: So, what modifications are required to get my current location?

Comment: In the location listener callback that you implemented as "this" you should be getting the location updates

Comment: @nosacky: You mean to say, I should be using 'Location' from below method:
       public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}